# How to calculate the CPU resources required to use ffmpeg to transcode a video stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have a SAAS software that does video transcoding using ffmpeg. The hardware is expected to have no GPU and other hardware acceleration technologies. The input video stream will have the following basic parameters: 1 video stream, full HD resolution, bitrate = 5500 kbps, h264 codec, audio codec is aac, 160 kbps. The desired output includes 3 video streams with the following parameters: - Stream 1: Full HD resolution, bitrate = 3500 kbps, h264 codec; - Stream 2: HD resolution, bitrate = 1800 kbps, h264 codec; - Stream 3: SD resolution, bitrate = 500, h264 codec. The sound is the same as the input stream, unchanged. The question is whether there is a specific calculation method or anyone has experience calculating the required hardware resources (CPU + Memory) for each 10 input streams and the requirements as I have stated?